# C# .Net MVC- How to get button onclick to updata string data in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a button that changes a string data in the database. Currently in the database, there is a table for AspNetUsers which contains a string column called Activated (default value is null). What I would like to happen is when a button is clicked, that null value becomes the value 'Yes' on buttonclick. How do I go about doing this with MVC? Thanks

This is the button Im calling in the view

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectMVC2.Models.ApplicationUser>

@foreach (var item in Model)
    {

@if (item.Activated == null)
            {


                using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "User", new { id = item.Id })){
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <td class="button btn-default" align="center">
                    <input type="submit" value="Activate" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </td>
                }
            }
            else if (item.Activated == "Yes")
            {
                <td class="c" align="center">
                    Activated already
                </td>
            }
```

This is the controller. There is a method called Update which I am calling for the button in the view

```
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    ApplicationDbContext context;
    private SqlConnection update;
    private SqlCommand set;

    public UserController()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    // GET: User
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var User = context.Users.ToList();
        return View(User);
    }
    public ActionResult Update(int id)
    {

        update = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\WinUser\Desktop\ProjectMVC2\ProjectMVC2\App_Data\aspnet-ProjectMVC2-20180223023456.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ProjectMVC2-20180223023456;Integrated Security=True");
        update.Open();
        set = new SqlCommand("UPDATE AspNetUsers SET Activated = 'Yes' ");

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

This Update method does not work. How can i fix this please? I appreciate any help. Thank you very much

Comment: The SqlCommand is never executed.

Comment: set.ExecuteNonQuery();  This will update all users in the table.  You need a Where statement to match the id.

Comment: Completely irrelevant comment, but I'd strongly suggest looking into EF, or any other ORM's. For smaller apps that do not need to scale, it's a perfect tool/process.

Comment: I dont want it to update all users in the table. Each user will have a button which should update their own row. The app im building for is just a small project for myself

Comment: You need a WHERE clause in your sql (based on the value of the `id` parameter)